# AngularJS: How to get $http result as returned value of a function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Inside my controller I need a function that takes a parameter and returned a URL from server. Something like this:

```
$scope.getPoster = function(title) {
    return $http.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + title + "&y=&plot=short&r=json");
};
```

And inside my view I need to pass the title this way and get result as `src` for `ng-src`:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="movie in movies">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="poster" ng-src="{{getPoster(movie.Title)}}" alt="{{movie.Title}}">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{movie.Title}}</h3>
            <p>{{movie.Owner}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know the HTTP communications on `$http` never ever return data that I need immediately because all communications are asynchronous So I need to use promise:

```
$scope.getPoster = function(title) {
    $http({ url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + title + "&y=&plot=short&r=json" }).
    then(function (response) {
        // How can I return response.data.Poster ? 
    });
};
```

So my question is that How can I return the response as result for `getPoster` function?
Any idea?

Comment: just `return responde.data.Poster`

Comment: I don't understand your question; you appear to have added the code you need, then surrounded it with a comment asking how to do it, presumably without ever testing it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass `movie` to `getPoster` function, instead of `title`, it should work; and bind a variable to `ng-src` instead of the return of the `getPoster` function, it should work.

Also, you could display a placeholder while you are waiting for the response:

HTML:

```
<img class="poster"
     ng-init="movie.imgUrl = getPoster(movie)"
     ng-src="{{movie.imgUrl}}"
     alt="{{movie.Title}}">
```

<sub>* Note that `ng-init` could certainly be replaced with an *in-controller initialization*.</sub>

JS:

```
$scope.getPoster = function(movie) {
    $http({ url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + movie.Title+ "&y=&plot=short&r=json" })
    .then(function (response) {
        movie.imgUrl = response.data.Poster;
    });
    return "/img/poster-placeholder.png";
};
```

Once the `response` is returned, `movie.imgUrl` is changed.

So, the image will automatically be updated with the new source in the next digest cycle.

With this example, you won't need to return the promise.

Comment: Thanks, But it applies for all of the result I want to show a poster for each movie.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi Actually, `imgUrl` should be specific for each `movie`... I will test it and make a fiddle tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `ng-repeat`, you can pass the whole movie object, and then can add a new property to it:

```
$scope.getPoster = function (movie) {
    $http({ url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + movie.Title + "&y=&plot=short&r=json" }).
            then(function (response) {
                // How can I return response.data.Poster ? 
                movie.imageUrl = response.data.Poster;
            });
};
```

and then bind `ngSrc`:

```
ng-src='{{movie.imageUrl}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/Lqbqbhn0/) of your case. Note, i have taken sample titles.

You can't call the function in ng-repeat. You need to get the values before its been loaded like using resolve.

```
     var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($http,$scope){

          $scope.movies =[{Title:'gene',Owner:'Alaksandar'},{Title:'alpha',Owner:'Me'}];
            angular.forEach($scope.movies,function(movie){
                $http.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+movie.Title+"&y=&plot=short&r=json").
                        success(function (response) {
                            movie['poster'] = response.Poster;
                    });


            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, this may work better for you.

Template:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="movie in getMovies">
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img class="poster" ng-src="{{movie.Poster}}" alt="{{movie.Title}}">
    <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{movie.Title}}</h3>
        <p>{{movie.Owner}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Service:

```
function getMovieData(movies) {
return {
    loadDataFromUrls: (function () {
        var apiList = movies;

        return $q.all(apiList.map(function (item) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + item + "&y=&plot=short&r=json"
            });
        }))
        .then(function (results) {
            var resultObj = {};
            results.forEach(function (val, i) {
                resultObj[i] = val.data;
            });
            return resultObj;        
        });
    })(movies)
};
};
```

Controller:

```
var movies = ["gladiator", "seven"];  

$scope.getMovies = getMovieData(movies);

function getMovieData(){
dataService.getMovieData(movies).loadDataFromUrls
  .then(getMovieDataSuccess)
  .catch(errorCallback);
}


function getMovieDataSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.getMovies = data;
    return data;
  }
```